# Wordpress wp_get_current_user() returns empty payload while a user is logged-in

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-rest-api

In Wordpress 6.2.2, I'm trying to define a rest api listener that will return the currently logged-in user.

I added the following code to my functions.php file (of my child theme) and it is responding to my requests in another browser tab.
However, I am getting the following result, even though in another tab I have a valid user (admin) logged-in.

**Result is always:**

```
{
"data": {},
"ID": 0,
"caps": [],
"cap_key": null,
"roles": [],
"allcaps": [],
"filter": null
}
```

**Code in functions.php:**

```
add_action('rest_api_init', function () {
    register_rest_route('mytheme/v1', '/current-user', array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => 'get_current_user1',
        'permission_callback' => function () {
            return true;
        }
    ));
});


function get_current_user1($request) {
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    return $user;
}
```

**Logged-in user shown in another browser tab:**

[image]

I tried this with TWO different WordPress sites, same result always.
What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For developers making manual Ajax requests, the nonce will need to be passed with each request. The API uses nonces with the action set to wp_rest. These can then be passed to the API via the _wpnonce data parameter (either POST data or in the query for GET requests), or via the X-WP-Nonce header. If no nonce is provided the API will set the current user to 0, turning the request into an unauthenticated request, even if you’re logged into WordPress.

Source:
https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/using-the-rest-api/authentication/#cookie-authentication